# convert Object to array

Tags: php, symfony

I ceated a function to convert a list of parent child to an object of class "city" :

```
   public static function createCity(array $config)
{
    $city= new City();

    $id=key($config);
    $label= $config[$id]['label'];

    $city->setId($id);
    $city->setLabel($label);

    $children = $config[$id]['childrens'];

    if(!empty($children)){
        foreach($children as $key_child => $child) {
            $children = array($key_child => $child);

            $city->addChild(self::createCity($children));

        }
    }
  return $city;
}
```

Now I would to creat a function to do the opposite => convert an object of type Class City to an array,so I do like that :

```
   public function getCityArray(City$rootCity)
{
        $result = array();

        $result['id'] = $rootCity->getId();
        $result['label']= $rootCity->getLabel();

    $children = $rootCity->getChildren();


    if ( !empty($children)) {
        foreach ($children as $key_child => $child) {

            $result['childrens'] = array($key_child => $child );

            $result[] = $this->getCityArray($child);
        }
    }

    return $result;

}
```

But it doesn't work because when I do var_dump('$result') so I have a list with no end and  the loop does not stop?

Comment: it looks like you are trying to insert an Array into an Array Index. is this correct `$result['childrens'] = array($key_child => $child );`  it looks like this might give you troubles to me.

Comment: So whats a good condition to stop recursion?

Comment: unless you declare a multi dimensional (spelling I know) array, I don't think that you can do `$result['childrens'] = array($key_child => $child );` and then the syntax would probably be wrong. I don't even know if PHP does multi-dimensional arrays. I might just be reading it wrong too, I am an amateur when it comes to PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Since I don't know have the full code, not sure if it will work. The class variable `$result` will contain the results.

```
$result = array();
public function getCityArray(City $rootCity) {

  $result['id'] = $rootCity->getId();
  $result['label']= $rootCity->getLabel();
  $children = $rootCity->getChildren();

  if ( !empty($children)) {
    $result['childrens'] = $children;
    $this->result[] = $result;
    foreach ($children as $key_child => $child) {
      $this->getCityArray($child);
    }
  }

}
```